# how to use gt::as_word output in a quarto file

Tags: r, quarto, gt

The {{gt}} package now includes a [function `as_word`](https://gt.rstudio.com/reference/as_word.html), which outputs the table as an OOXML string.

I would like to use this to insert tables into the word output of a Quarto document.

I thought this would work.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: docx
---


```{r}
library(gt)

gtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(mfr, model) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:2) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = md("Data listing from **gtcars**"),
    subtitle = md("`gtcars` is an R dataset")
  ) %>%
  as_word()
```
````

But the word output is just the OOXML string, like this. How can I make the table appear as a table in the quarto word output?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to print an OOXML string for this purpose I guess – it works with the `print()` method for docx output:

````
```{r, echo=F}
library(gt)
gtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(mfr, model) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:2) %>%
  gt() %>%
  tab_header(
    title = "Data listing from gtcars",
    subtitle = "gtcars is an R dataset"
  )
```
````

[image]

(There's some trouble with the markdown code though, probably a bug.  I've removed `md()`.)

Comment: Thanks, Martin. As it turns out, I was running a slightly outdated version of either {{gt}} or {{quarto}}. Upon updating both, the table now renders as expected without the use of `as_word`. Let this be a lesson to me to always update the packages!

Comment: Glad that it works for you now! I'm curious: does it work with `md()` as used in your question. Doesn't work for me with current (and dev) versions of gt and quarto.